# Scheduling an IBM SPSS Modeler stream

Tags: scheduled-tasks, spss-modeler

I'm looking to add a scheduler for my IBM SPSS modeler stream so that it pulls the data and saves in the file on regular basis (once in a week or monthly). But I don't see any scheduler node/activity in 18.2.1 version of SPSS. Is there any possibility of implementing this? What are the options available?

Answer (score 1):

My company uses SPSS Modeler heavily. We use [IBM SPSS Collaboration and Deployment Services](https://www.ibm.com/products/spss-collaboration-deployment-services) (CADS) for version control of streams and deployment.

There should however be the possibility to use the [SPSS Modeler Scripting Language](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-modeler/18.0.0?topic=arguments-invoking-software) to call a stream and use some other [scheduling program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software) to schedule this task.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to make use of the BATCH functionality of the Windows, along with the command line execution functionality of the SPSS MODELER.
For example, you can write a Windows batch file that will execute your stream in specific time (in seconds) intervals.

What I mean is something like this:

```
:loop
"C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Modeler\18.0\bin\clemb.exe" -server -hostname 10.23.2.137 -port 28056 -username yourwindowsusername -password yourwindowspassword -stream "DAILY_LOG.str" -P:databasenode.datasource="{\"databasename\",yourdatabaseusername,yourdatabasepassword,false}" -P:databaseexport.datasource="{\"databasename\",yourdatabaseusername,yourdatabasepassword,false}" -execute
timeout /t 300 /nobreak
goto :loop
```

Then call the Windows Scheduler and schedule the above batch file to be execute upon the PC's startup.

This works fine for me in my production environment.